# How to change options when searching in md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, md-autocomplete

How to change options when i am typing in . It is not working properly when I type filter not working  its show all the list i want change list text according to search please help me this.

```
<md-autocomplete
    ng-disabled="Ctrlmain.isDisabled"
    md-no-cache="Ctrlmain.noCache"
    md-selected-item="Ctrlmain.selectedItem"
    md-search-text="Ctrlmain.campaignname"
    md-selected-item-change="Ctrlmain.filltextbox(item)"
    md-items="item in Ctrlmain.getMatches(Ctrlmain.campaignname)  | unique:'campaign_name'"
    md-item-text="item.campaign_name"
    md-min-length="0"
    placeholder="Pick an Angular repository"
    md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
        <md-item-template>
            <span class="item-title">                                
                <span> {{item.campaign_name}} </span>
            </span>
        </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Angular Method

```
complete(str){

    var output = [];
    angular.forEach(this.viewData,function(campaignname){
      if(campaignname.campaign_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase())>=0){
        output.push(campaignname.campaign_name);

      };
    });
  return output.campaign_name;
}

filltextbox(st){   
   return st;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning matches on `md-search-text-change` doesn't work. Your `md-autocomplete` is bound to `Ctrlmian.viewData`. If that is to work, you have to modify the said array at the end of `complete` function. Besides your code is essentially wrong when you try to return `output.campaign_name` where `output` is an array. Or you can try it this way...

```
<md-autocomplete
    ng-disabled="Ctrlmain.isDisabled"
    md-no-cache="Ctrlmain.noCache"
    md-selected-item="Ctrlmain.selectedItem"
    md-search-text="Ctrlmain.campaignname"
    md-selected-item-change="Ctrlmain.filltextbox(item)"
    md-items="item in Ctrlmain.getMatches(Ctrlmain.campaignname)  | unique:'campaign_name'"
    md-item-text="item.campaign_name"
    md-min-length="0"
    placeholder="Pick an Angular repository"
    md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
        <md-item-template>
            <span class="item-title">                                
                <span> {{item.campaign_name}} </span>
            </span>
        </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Notice I've gotten rid of `md-search-text-change`. I'm using your filter function to dynamically render items for `md-autocomplete` as below.

```
getMatches(str) {
    var output = [];
    angular.forEach(this.viewData,function(campaignname) {
        if(campaignname.campaign_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase())>=0) {
            output.push(campaignname);
        };
    });
    return output;
}
```